# Sailsjs Session access during custom onConnect in socket.io

Tags: session, sails.js, socket.io

I'm trying to group all my socket.io connection into groups.
I want 1 group for each sails.js session.
My first goal is authentificate all tabs in a same time.

So I tried to do this with `onConnect` in `config/sockets.js` like that :

```
onConnect: function(session, socket) {
  // By default: do nothing
  // This is a good place to subscribe a new socket to a room, inform other users that
  // someone new has come online, or any other custom socket.io logic
  if (typeof session.socket == 'undefined'){
    session.socket = [];
  }
  session.socket.push(socket.id);
  session.save();

  console.log(session, socket);
},

// This custom onDisconnect function will be run each time a socket disconnects
onDisconnect: function(session, socket) {

  // By default: do nothing
  // This is a good place to broadcast a disconnect message, or any other custom socket.io logic
  if(Array.isArray(session.socket)){
    var i = session.socket.indexOf(socket.id);
    if(i != -1) {
      session.socket.splice(i, 1);
      session.save();
    }
  }
  console.log(session, socket);
},
```

But I realize that session doesn't save my modifications.
I tried a `session.save` but sailsjs doesn't know `req` !

```
Session.set(sessionKey, req.session, function (err) {
```

I want to access to sails.js sesion but I don't know how to do it.

I tried to search a solution but now, after 6 hours of search I think it's time to requiered some help !

Thanks and sorry for my poor english (I'm french).

Answer (score 1):

There appears to be a bug in the implementation of `onConnect` and `onDisconnect` in Sails v0.9.x.  You can work around it for now by adding the following line before a call to `session.save` in those methods:

```
global.req = {}; global.req.session = session;
```

then changing `session.save()` to:

```
session.save(function(){delete global.req;});
```

That will provide the missing `req` var as a global, and then delete the global (for safety) after the session is saved.

Note that this issue only affects sessions in the `onConnect` and `onDisconnect` methods; inside of controller code `session.save` should work fine.

Thanks for pointing this out!

Comment: I find that this bug is still there in version 0.10.0-rc8, I've tried the workaround but it only works sometimes. Any tips?